# Imputing null values in column using the mean of other column values in pandas

Tags: python, data-science

Length of my data-set is 20216100

There are two columns in my data-set `month` and `cloud_coverage`.

`cloud coverage` has 43% `null` values.

Now I have tried to fill `null` values with average `cloud_coverage` in for a `month`.

```
cloud_cov_mean=list(train.groupby('month')['cloud_coverage'].mean())
cc_dic={}

for index,val in enumerate(cloud_cov_mean):
    cc_dic[index+1]=val

null_list=cc_df[cc_df['cloud_coverage'].isnull()].index.tolist()
```

**Once I execute below code it runs for hours without any output**.

```
for val in null_list:
    cc_month=cc_df.loc[val,'month']
    imp_val=cc_dic[cc_month]

cc_df.loc[val,'cloud_coverage']=imp_val
```

Is there any alternative way to impute the `null` values using above logic?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), to each subset of `months`

```
# create dictionary of 'month' as key and 'mean of month' as value
cc_dic = train.groupby('month')['cloud_coverage'].mean().to_dict()
#for mnth in train.month.unique():
for key, value in cc_dic.items():
    train.loc[train.month == key,'cloud_coverage'] = train.loc[train.month == key,'cloud_coverage'].fillna(value)
```

or assign value back to each month where the value is `na`

```
cc_dic = train.groupby('month')['cloud_coverage'].mean().to_dict()
for key, value in cc_dic.items():
    train.loc[((train.month == key) & (train.cloud_coverage.isnull())),'cloud_coverage'] = value
```